# TypeError operand when looping through list of lists and t-testing

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list of lists, 24 with indexes 0-23 representing hours of the day. There are some that are empty but I have even tried filling them with 0s. I am trying to t test starting at the first list vs the next one, and if p>.05 then append the lists together, then test the combined list vs the next list. If p<.05 then they won't be combined and the next pair of lists will be tested. For example, if list 5 vs 6 gives p>.05 a new list of 5&6 is created and tested vs 7, if this is also p>.05 then 7 is appended to the list and the whole list is tested vs 8, etc. If 5&6 vs 7 is p<.05 then they will not be appended and 7 will be tested vs 8 instead and the process starts over. I have this code currently:

```
TestList=[]


for i in range(0,24):

    TestList.append([])

for temp in paxbinfull.itertuples():
    for i in range(int(temp.Pax)):
        TestList[int(temp.hr)].append(int(temp.bucket)*10)



TestList = [[int(j) for j in i] for i in TestList]
for i in range(len(TestList)):
    if TestList[i] ==[]:
        TestList[i] = [1]


from scipy.stats import ttest_ind
i = 0   
j = 1
left_list = TestList[0]
right_list = TestList[1]
list_groups = {}
while i <= 22:
    p = ttest_ind(left_list,right_list,equal_var=False,nan_policy='omit')[1]
        if p >= 0.05:
            left_list.append(right_list)
        elif p < 0.05:
            list_groups[i] = left_list
            left_list = TestList[j]
    right_list = TestList[j+1]
    i = i+1
    j = j+1
```

I get an error that says "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'" and it says it is from this line of the module: arrmean = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, keepdims=True).

Any help is appreciated, I feel like the logic is ok but maybe not? No idea what the problem is I can't understand the error.

[List of lists that contains all the data that I am t-testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lDDX.png)

Comment: The error message says you were trying to add an integer and a list, but the line you quoted does not contain a plus sign.  It would help if you could construct and post a [mcve].

Comment: @DennisSparrow I will work on that, but I thought that is what it meant, don't know why it is saying that...